# Instagram API Permissions Rejected for iOS App to Pull Public Content Data

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My iOS app needs to use Instagram API to load some images, user feedback based on geo location. I requested **public_content** permissions from Instagram team but got rejected with explanations below even though I filled out as much info as possible. Note I have my app in development only and website looks very minimal but some designs and lots of description was submitted for review.

How to resolve this issue of getting these basic permissions? I googled and I notice this is a common problem.

> **General issues:** Invalid Use Case: The use case descrbied in your submission notes, screencast and website is not a valid use case that
>   we allow on our Platform. Please see our Permissions Review and valid
>   use cases description (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/)
>   for more information.
>
> **public_content:** This permission (public_content) does not support the use case you described in your submission notes, screencast and
>   website. Please review Login Permissions
>   (http://instagram.com/developer/authorization/) for a comprehensive
>   list of permissions and valid use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps. I have tried two times but our app was declined. I will write the submission text one more time. I also want to go more into detail as the new FAQ says that Instagram expects a very detailed submision.

Cheers, Christian

**FAQ**

**My submission was rejected but it was a valid use case. What should I do?**

A common reason for rejecting a submission is that we do not have enough information to make an assessment of your app. This can happen if your submission was too short, if it missed important information, if you did not provide a good screencast, your website is not working, etc. Before you submit for review again, make sure to provide a long and clear explanation of what your app does and how you use every permission. Make sure also to provide a video screencast and to follow all our Platform Policies.

**What should I write in the submission?**

The submission should be long enough for us to understand exactly what your app does and why you need the permissions you are asking for. If your submission is too short or does not explain all parts of your integration, then we may not be able to understand and approve your app. For example, your submission should explain what does your app or company do, which of the approved use cases your integration falls into, who will be using your app, how do your user authenticate with your app, how you use the API to power your integration, how does your product use the data acquired from Instagram, etc.

**What should I show in the video screencast?**

The video screencast is a very important part of a submission and cannot be omitted. Please make sure that the video clearly shows how your application works, including any Instagram login experience and the usage of every permission you are requesting. Since your app may still be in sandbox mode, you can use data from sandbox users to showcase the integration.

**My company is working with multiple clients, should I submit one app per project?**

No, we do not approve apps that are created for one-off projects (e.g. a hashtag campaign, an event, a website). You should use a single client_id across all your integrations.

**Can I revoke a submission if I made a mistake?**

You can't cancel a submission that is in progress. You will need to wait until the submission has been reviewed before you can start a new one.